# What does this UFW entry mean?

Tags: networking, logs, firewall, ufw

I've found this recent entry in ufw.log:

```
RaspberryPi kernel: [1046588.133562] [UFW BLOCK] IN=wlan0 OUT= MAC=mac_address SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

My default ufw policy is to deny incoming and allow outgoing. In the past i've blocked incoming connections from 224.0.0.0/24 since the router(?) was spamming my ufw.log with such entries. However, this entry is new.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29

Comment: It is common services services/devices announcing their presence via multicast. There is no use in blocking them, and in fact you can break some services.

Comment: So it's nothing I should worry about?